# SD probability problem involving chi-square distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, standard-deviation

Preparing for an exam in statistics, I have been pondering the following problem:

Given that in country X 14 % of people hold a university degree, find the probability that for random sample of size 200 the standard deviation is less than 20.

Trying to compute this resulted in ridiculously high values for the chi-square-distribution.

Any input would be warmly welcomed.

Comment: Indeed, the sample std is between 0.2 and 0.45 with probability close to 1. 
Maybe there is a typo in the question?

Comment: Hello there! I'm afraid this is the question verbatim.